# How to conditionally stop function execution and show an alert?

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

My page contains text boxes and a submit button. If the form is submitted, an alert box would pop-out and would state if the inputs are valid or invalid.

Here's the code:

```
    alert(valid ? "Valid" : "Invalid")
```

But what I really want is for the page to proceed if the inputs are *valid*, and the alert box will only pop-out when it's *invalid*.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current logic has nothing to do with whether or not the alert is executed. It only determines what the value of the alert is (what string is shown).

```
if (!valid) {
  alert("Hey, it's invalid!");
}
```

`valid ? "Valid" : "Invalid"` is ternary that says: "If valid, use the string 'Valid', else use the string 'Invalid'.

So, if variable `valid` evaluates to true, it's just like doing this:

```
alert('Valid');
```

If `valid` evaluates to false:

```
alert('Invalid');
```

Instead, you want this:

```
//if "valid" evaluates to false
if (!valid) {
  //alert the user
  alert("Hey, it's invalid!");
  //you could "return false" here to stop the rest of the block from executing
  return false;
}
//if "valid" is true, it just keeps going
//OR you could use an else statement (valid is true)
else {
  //this isn't necessary if you "return false" above
}
```

Comment: I'm new when it comes to jQuery. But already figured it out. Here's the code that I've use. Thanks for your quick response.
if(!valid) {alert("Check for empty"); return false;}

Comment: @LoganWayne this has nothing to do with jQuery. It's just javascript. If you appreciate my answer, don't forget to click accept!

Comment: Have to wait for two minutes. Thanks! I used Javascript in my first run, but I think I have to change to jQuery because of it's finer validation. (In Javascript, white spaces are being accepted as valid input and can't seem to find an easier way to block it)

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript library. You are using JavaScript regardless. You might use some of jQuery's functions or facilities, but these are all written in JavaScript.

Comment: @LoganWayne You're not understanding :( jQuery is not a language. It's a set of javascript functions (a library). jQuery is javascript just as much as this: `function foo() { }` Same thing. All of the code in your question and in my answer is just javascript.

Comment: LOL! Yeah. Sorry for the misunderstanding but I get it.:D

Comment: @m59 You forgot to make the row that begins with `you could "return false"` as a comment.

Comment: @some hmm, I missed this comment until just now. Thanks for the heads up!!